# DeprecationWarning for Sequelize in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

While upgrading the version for sequelize to the latest (current 6.25.3) version, It shows no errors but gives the below warning:

**(node:58292) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)**

Thanks for the answers !

Tried to find the solution for it on the sequelize documentation.

Comment: what happened when you used `--trace-deprecation`?

Comment: **It showed me:**

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/shrey/Documents/smartProof-certification-backend/...'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.0

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the **operatorsAliases: false** option used in your sequelize config file to **operatorsAliases: 0**.

In the latest version of sequelize, the boolean values '1','0' will be used instead of true,false. So try that, It might not show the deprecation warning again.

Happy coding !!!